# How to anchor a point on one object to another for animation?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I'm trying to animate 2 objects which are essentially 1 when combined. There is 1 point on the "parent" object which needs to follow or be "anchored" to another point on the second object and needs to stay anchored to this point throughout an animation. Is it possible to anchor one point to another throughout an animation without merging points?

Comment: Check out the Hook modifier which would be ideal for that. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/hooks.html#hooks) is the Blender manual section on Hooks and there are lots of YT tutorials online showing how to use it. - You can hook to an object as well as just to vertices BTW.

Comment: isn't simple parenting that what you want?

Comment: You can select the second object, shift select the parent, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices of the mesh of the second, press Ctrl P > Make Vertex Parent

Comment: but could you please show the exact situation with a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution similar to what was described by @[John Eason](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/104232/john-eason). This setup has an Empty object which is used as the anchor or [`Hook`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html) to the left object. First select the Empty then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the object to be hooked and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*. Then select the point or vertex you need to be anchored or hooked and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> *> Hook to Selected Object*. Then <kbd>tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode* and select the Empty object and <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the parent object. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> *> Object*.

[image]

Comment: The problem is I have a point that is animated and is moving, but I need another point from another game object to be "anchored" to the already animated point. Hooking the 2 points together does not make the pint follow the other, its close but doesnt "anchor". Parenting didnt seem to work, and parenting just breaks a lot and ends up "teleporting" objects off into the workspace in random places.

Comment: Here is a link to a gif showing a point that eventually reaches a point, but I would like the 1 point to be anchored to the other.

https://ibb.co/dfFx4hz